# Python calculate count of common values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries.

```
last_list=[
    {'name': 'Rat', 'value': 3},
    {'name': 'Cat', 'value': 1},
    {'name': 'Sanke', 'value': 1},
    {'name': 'Rat', 'value': 1},
    {'name': 'Cat', 'value': 2},
]
```

What I want is to calculate the sum of the common values.

expected o/p

```
name_list = ['Rat', 'Cat', 'Sanke']
name_count = [4, 3, 1]
```

my code

```
name_list, name_count = [], []
for last in last_list:
    count = last['value']
   if last['name'] not in labels_:
      name_list.append(last['name'])
   if last['name'] in labels_:
       count = count + last['value']
  name_count.append(count)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

last_list=[
    {'name': 'Rat', 'value': 3},
    {'name': 'Cat', 'value': 1},
    {'name': 'Sanke', 'value': 1},
    {'name': 'Rat', 'value': 1},
    {'name': 'Cat', 'value': 2},
]

res = defaultdict(int)
for i in last_list:
    res[i['name']] += i['value']
    
name_list, name_count = zip(*res.items())
print(name_list, name_count)
```

**Output:**

```
('Rat', 'Cat', 'Sanke') 
(4, 3, 1)
```